# YouTube videos in Safari don't react to mouse in full screen mode

Tags: safari, youtube

I use Safari and MacOS version 10.14.6

Recently I am facing a problem when playing youtube videos in full screen mode.

Earlier when a video is running in full screen mode, I could use the controls on the video player to drag and fast forward the video.

Now when I make the video full screen it plays but it doesn't react to move movement. So I cannot change the volume or cannot use the slider to jump to a position in the video.

The only way to do this is to switch out of full screen mode of video.

This problem started only after a recent update.